# What is the value of $\sin(53^\circ)$ equal to in cos? (Unit Circle)

Tags: trigonometry

I tried this and I only got $\sin( 53^\circ)= \sin( 127^\circ).$ How do I find the equal value in cosine or tangent? Please help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

$sin(90^\circ + \theta )= cos(\theta)$

$sin(90^\circ - \theta )= cos(\theta)$.

So:

$sin(53^\circ)=sin(90^\circ - 37^\circ )= cos(37^\circ)$.

It would better if you learn more about them here [Khanacademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/trigonometry-right-triangles/sine-and-cosine-of-complementary-angles/a/sine-and-cosine-are-cofunctions).

Comment: is that a rule?

Comment: Yes, they are called complementary angles.

Comment: Thank you, appreciated!!!

Comment: @MERcurialKG I have updated the answer with the link for proof.

Comment: Thanks,  i just finish watching the video .

Comment: @MERcurialKG You should also see the shortcut method to know all such formulae, both supplementary and complimentary for $sin, cosec, cos, sec, tan, cot$. For this you need to know the respective quadrants in which they are positive and evacuate accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the identity $\sin x^\circ = \cos {(90^\circ-x^\circ)}$ so $\sin{53^\circ}=\sin{127^\circ}=\cos{(127^\circ-90^\circ)}=\cos{37^\circ}.$

I can't think of an simple way to express it in tangent.

Comment: Is that some kind of rule?

Comment: Yes. It can be proved by the unit circle.

Comment: Okay Thanks for helping out!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: ? what do u mean? @jasonkim

Comment: :P The question asker can "accept" answers, meaning clicking the gray check mark.